# How to split in log-in form

Tags: java, swing, split, jcreator

I'm making a log-in design using JCreator. How do I parse the txt file using split and put it in the right place?

```
public logins()
{
    super ("logins");
    Container c=getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,5,5));

    lbl1=new JLabel("USERNAME:");
    lbl2=new JLabel("PASSWORD:");
    txt1=new JTextField(10);
    psw1=new JPasswordField(10);
    btnLog=new JButton("LOG-IN");
    btnCancel=new JButton("CANCEL");

    c.add(lbl1);
    c.add(txt1);
    c.add(lbl2);
    c.add(psw1);
    c.add(btnLog);
    c.add(btnCancel);

    btnLog.addActionListener(this);
    btnCancel.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(350,150);
    setVisible(true);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==btnCancel)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btnLog)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader data=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("user.txt"));
            String userName=txt1.getText();
            String userLine=data.readLine();
            boolean found=false;

            while(userLine!=null)
            {
                if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase(userLine))
                {
                    found=true;
                    break;

                }
                userLine=data.readLine();
            }

            if(found==true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ACCESS GRANTED");

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ACCESS DENIED");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,err.getMessage());
        }
    }



}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    logins lo=new logins();
    lo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with your code exactly? What is the structure of your file? Why isn't `data.readLine()` good enough?

Comment: what is "the right place" ?

Comment: How are you splitting the line? do you want to split it based on comma or spaces or anything else? I think you are checking user credentials from text file. Correct me if I am wrong.